# How to convert mouse position to world coordinates?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to see which object is clicked for a fixed Z position. I am using perspective projection.

For the rendering of my objects, I use:

```
glm::mat4 mvp = m_ProjectionView * model; // Inversed
```

For the calculation of the world position of the mouse, I have tried the following, but it is not converting correctly.

```
glm::mat4 projViewInverse = glm::inverse( projection * view );
glm::vec4 cursorWorldPosition = glm::vec4( projViewInverse * glm::vec4( ( mousePosX / scrWidth ) * 2.0f - 1.0f, ( mousePosY / scrHeight ) * 2.0f - 1.0f, -1, 1 ) );

cursorWorldPosition.w = 1.0f / cursorWorldPosition.w;
cursorWorldPosition.x *= cursorWorldPosition.w;
cursorWorldPosition.y *= cursorWorldPosition.w;
cursorWorldPosition.z *= cursorWorldPosition.w;
```

Comment: You definitively forgot the division by w for the final result. However, I'm not sure if that is all there is. Can you elaborate on what "is not converting correctly" exactly means?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't forget it. But I had forgotton to copy it into the question. Well, the position changes, but it does not scale to the correct value. I think this has something to do with the perspective not being right.

Comment: Conceptually, your unprojection math is correct. I'm not sure if you really want to unproject a point on the near plane, though. What you also forgot is to consider that OpenGL uses bottom left as origin, while mouse coords typically are top left, so y must be flipped.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the coordinates are just a little off. They are not precisely accurate, although almost.

Comment: depending on the projection matrix in use, there might be noticable deviations due to limits of floating point precision. But it is again unclear if this is the issue here, or something else. Your muse position might be slightly off because you divide values in the range [0,size-1] by size. You also might want to consider assumming the mouse position at the center of the pixel, not at its edge.

Comment: Maybe it is incorrect because the Z values of the `cursorWorldPosition` does not match with the Z value of the object's world position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92429/discussion-between-z0q-and-derhass).